# Autodesk Forge viewer: Directly load a SVF?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

As the official documentation states, you can upload a source file to OSS and translate it, once in your bucket, to a SVF with the Model Derivative API.

But is it possible to skip the translation step, directly uploading a SVF project (for example, one of these: https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/gallery) and loading into the web viewer?

I haven't been able neither to do it nor find any documentation yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Instead of loading the Model Derivative service "manifest" using the [Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Document/#load-documentid-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) method, and then loading a specific "viewable" from the manifest using the [Viewer3D#loadDocumentNode](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#loaddocumentnode-avdocument-manifestnode-options) method, you can just call the viewer's [loadModel](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#loadmodel-url-options-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) method and provide an actual URL to your SVF file.

Note however that the Forge Viewer assets (JavaScript, CSS files, icons, etc.) should still be coming from the Autodesk domain. In other words, we do not officially support running the application offline. If you need to support workflows where your users could be *temporarily* disconnected from the internet, please refer to https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/disconnected-workflows.

Comment: So, I could follow the steps of the Prepare a File for the Viewer tutorial (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-file4viewer/) but, instead of starting the translation job, calling the URN returned after uploading my svf, as a zip to the Object Storage Service?

Comment: You'll always need to call the translation job to actually _generate_ the SVF. But when the SVF is ready, it is possible to download the SVF (and all the assets it references), and serve it from your custom server.

Comment: Here's one example of how the SVF can be downloaded: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils/blob/develop/samples/download-svf.js.

Comment: But what I mean is to directly download a SVF and load into the viewer, so no SVF needs to be generated because you already have one. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, the `loadModel` method I mention in my answer is used to load existing SVFs from custom URLs, for example, if you have your SVFs in AWS S3 already.

Comment: I'm not able to use the function in my JS script, I'm calling `Autodesk.Viewing.Document.loadModel(url, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback)` but I get a TypeError (cannot read property 'loadModel' of undefined). 
I am trying to store the SVF as a zip by calling first `developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/xabicasado/objects/11_Jay_Street.zip`but I also can't then call to it with th previous function, am I forgetting or doing some step wrong?

Comment: Please follow the link I posted in the answer - the `loadModel` is a method on the `Viewer3D` class, not on the `Document`.

Comment: You are right, my fault, thanks for the reply. I am going to accept the answer as it is the correct way to load a SVF, but I am still stuck at the SVF upload process to my bucket and I am not able to load into the viewer as I can't complete the previous steps ([this concrete one](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-file4viewer/task2-upload_source_file_to_oss/)).

Comment: Btw. serving the SVFs is typically done when customers *cannot* (for whichever reason) store the data in Forge. But if you are planning on uploading the content to Forge anyway, why not just use the SVFs the usual way? When you upload a design into Forge and translate it with Model Derivative service, the SVF output is stored in the Model Derivative service itself, and anytime you load it with Forge Viewer, you are opening the existing SVF.

Comment: Because one of the requirements of the project is that the user already has locally the SVF and want to upload directly in that format, so we need to upload a SVF and load into the viewer, which we have not been able to achieve yet.

Comment: I see. In that case I don't think the OSS (object storage service) component of the Data Management service is the right solution. If you want to serve the SVFs (and all the files they reference) from a custom origin, it would be better to use a storage service that can act as a static HTTP server. This can be done with [AWS S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HostingWebsiteOnS3Setup.html) or with [Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=portal) for example.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, you really helped me to understand which should be our upload process. To close this, is there alink to the official documentation about how to reference some SVF model from our server or, more specifically, which should be the index file from the server to reference in the loadModel function?

Comment: You're welcome! I've just provided a code snippet for exactly this in another Stack Overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64849209/how-to-view-a-local-stored-svf-files-using-the-forge-viewer/64855588#64855588. Take a look.

Comment: Glad we could help :) Cheers!