# Uploading translated SVF file to OSS Bucket in Autodesk Forge API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm working with the Autodesk Forge API and have successfully translated a file using the derivativesApi.TranslateAsync method. Now, I would like to upload the translated SVF file to an OSS (Object Storage Service) Bucket.

I've tried using the derivativesApi.GetDerivativeManifestAsync method to obtain the translated file content as a byte array. However, I'm unsure of the correct way to upload this file to the OSS Bucket.

Could someone provide guidance on how to upload the translated SVF file to the OSS Bucket using the Autodesk Forge API? I would greatly appreciate any code examples or suggestions on the best approach.

```
   [HttpPost]
[Route("/api/aps/callback/designautomation")]
public async Task<IActionResult> OnCallback(string id, string outputFileName,string rootFile , [FromBody] dynamic body)
{
    Console.WriteLine("OnCallback 1");
    try
    {
        // your webhook should return immediately! we can use Hangfire to schedule a job
        JObject bodyJson = JObject.Parse((string)body.ToString());
        await _hubContext.Clients.Client(id).SendAsync("onComplete", bodyJson.ToString());

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            byte[] bs = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(bodyJson["reportUrl"]?.Value<string>());
            string report = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bs);
            await _hubContext.Clients.Client(id).SendAsync("onComplete", report);
        }

        // OAuth token
        dynamic oauth = await OAuthController.GetInternalAsync();

        ObjectsApi objectsApi = new ObjectsApi();
        objectsApi.Configuration.AccessToken = oauth.access_token;

        ApiResponse<dynamic> res = await objectsApi.getS3DownloadURLAsyncWithHttpInfo(
                                    NickName.ToLower() + "-design",
                                    outputFileName, new Dictionary<string, object> {
                                        { "minutesExpiration", 15.0 },
                                        { "useCdn", true }
                                    });
        await _hubContext.Clients.Client(id).SendAsync("downloadResult", (string)(res.Data.url));
        Console.WriteLine("Congrats!");

        res = await objectsApi.GetObjectDetailsAsyncWithHttpInfo(
            NickName.ToLower() + "-design",
            outputFileName);



        DerivativesApi derivativesApi = new DerivativesApi();
        derivativesApi.Configuration.AccessToken = oauth.access_token;
        var formats = new List<JobPayloadItem> {
        new JobPayloadItem (JobPayloadItem.TypeEnum.Svf, new List<JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum> {
            JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum._2d, JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum._3d })
        };
        var urn = Base64Encode(res.Data.objectId);
        var payload = new JobPayload(
            new JobPayloadInput(urn,true, rootFile),
            new JobPayloadOutput(formats)
        );

        res = await derivativesApi.TranslateAsyncWithHttpInfo(payload);

        await _hubContext.Clients.Client(id).SendAsync("urn", (string)urn);

        // Upload the translated file to the OSS Bucket
        string ossBucketName = NickName.ToLower() + "-design";
        string translatedFileName = "nazwa.svf"; // Replace with the actual translated file name

        // Read the content of the translated file
        byte[] translatedFileBytes = await derivativesApi.GetDerivativeManifestAsync(oauth.access_token, (string)urn, null, null);

        // Upload the file to the OSS Bucket
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(translatedFileBytes))
        {
            await objectsApi.UploadObjectAsync(ossBucketName, translatedFileName, null, memoryStream, null, null, null);
        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    // ALWAYS return ok (200)
    return Ok();
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to generate **SVF** for a model in order to view it in the **Autodesk Viewer**:

- generate the **SVF** for it using the **Model Derivative** service (I'm pretty sure this was working already in your project when I looked). In this case you do not interact with the **SVF** directly - **Model Derivative** service takes care of that. Once you started the translation (e.g. using **TranslateAsyncWithHttpInfo**) your job is done. When the translation is finished you can just pass the **urn** of the file to the **Viewer**
- generate the **SVF** on the **Design Automation** service. This is an option in the case of some of the engines, e.g. **Inventor** - see e.g. [CreateSVFPlugin](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-configurator-inventor/tree/master/AppBundles/CreateSVFPlugin) 
  In this case you'll have to store the generated files (**SVF** is a bunch of files organized into folders/subfolders) somewhere (e.g. directly on your server) and make them available for the **Viewer** 
  See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64820847/4654233

Comment: "When the translation is finished you can just pass the urn of the file to the Viewer" It works, properly. I would like to speed up the operation of the application, so after translation I want to send the svf file to the oss bucket. In the future, if the user asks to see a combination that has already been executed, I'd like to load the svf directly, skipping the DA and translation steps.

Comment: If you use the Model Derivative API to generate the SVF, then you can just keep the file and the associated SVF - if you store the resulting files under a different name each time then you can keep the SVF of all the previous designs: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/file-versioning-buckets